# How can I fix the Unsafe use of a nullable receiver error?

Tags: android, kotlin

The Code A is from [camera-samples](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/GalleryFragment.kt).

But Android Studio compiler displays the following warning information

*Unsafe use of a nullable receiver of type Array?*

How can I fix it ?

**Code A**

```
private lateinit var mediaList: MutableList<File>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)  
        val rootDirectory = File(args.rootDirectory)

        mediaList = rootDirectory.listFiles { file ->
            EXTENSION_WHITELIST.contains(file.extension.toUpperCase())
        }.sorted().reversed().toMutableList()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Although I can't reproduce your issue, you can try to add `?` at the end of the object which is not 100% not null.

After that you need to handle the case if object is really null (provide default value).

For example:

```
val list: List<String>? = null
val firstValue = list?.first() ?: "default value"
```

In the example above, the code would not compile with just `list.first()`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var name: String? = null
    var _name = ""
    
    
    var value = name ?: "" //empty value 

private lateinit var mediaList: MutableList<File>

for lateInit use `isInitialized`  check


    if(this::mediaList.isInitialized && null!=mediaList && mediaList.size>0){
    
    }
```